# How i can retrieve data in Rest Api from Universal Windows App?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, uri

I want to send data from Universal windows Application via URI to rest api .

If it is text i can solve that easily

```
string WebData = wc.DownloadString("http://restapic.azurewebsites.net/WebForm1.aspx?func=dd&hodn=WW")
```

but what to do if i want to pass Value like int or name which i dont know ? For example i want to enter in universal windows app into textbox number 199 and then send it .

I can do something like :

```
string WebData = wc.DownloadString("http://restapic.azurewebsites.net/WebForm1.aspx?func=dd&hodn=WW&value="+myNumber)
```

but then it ask for declaration of my number in this file....

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like following.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8880/");
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/product/1").Result;
```